# Make a div fullwidth minus X amount of px

Tags: css

There is a `logo` div which has width set to `25%` but `280px` max, which is usually the case and it almost never takes `25%`. I need another `wrapper` div  to take all the remaining width of a screen.

[JsFiddel demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f4av2c3y/)

Comment: what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Why not use `padding` ?

Comment: I guess, because there's no `min-width` for padding

Answer (score 0):

With a fixed width/percentage logo, you could use the CSS calc() method on the second div.
Example: `width: calc(100% - 280px)`

But in this case the logo width changes, so I recommend you to let the second div `display:flex`. Example:

```css
body {
width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;  
  background:darkslategrey;
}

#img {
 width:25%;  
 max-width:280px;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
}

#div {
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  background: tomato;  
}
```

```html
<img id=img src=http://i.imgur.com/Goy7oBy.gif alt=img><div id=div></div>
```